# Which DLLs do I need to install PHP 7.3 NTS-64 on Windows Nanoserver?

Tags: php, windows, iis, fastcgi

The windows installer for the runtime dlls does not run on the nanoserver https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40131. I have tried to manually copy vcruntime140.dll to the system32 folder. When I try to run php from the command line it just renders a blank line and goes to a new command prompt. Am I missing some DLLs?

Comment: For information about "Configure a PHP Website on IIS", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configure-a-php-website-on-iis

Comment: I did not see a list of the DLLs required to run PHP 7.3.

Comment: Can your PHP website run on windows?

Comment: Yes, it runs on a larger Windows server core docker image.